# Prophet spitting water on someone's face What does it mean?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, sahih-bukhari, reward

[This](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/4/55) hadith from Bukhari states that

> **Mahmud bin Ar-Rabi who was the person on whose face the Prophet (ﷺ)
>   had ejected a mouthful of water** from his family's well while he was a
>   boy, and `Urwa (on the authority of Al-Miswar and others) who
>   testified each other, said, "Whenever the Prophet (ﷺ) , performed
>   ablution, his companions were nearly fighting for the remains of the
>   water."

Is it a mistranslation, or what was the meaning of this act of the prophet ?

Comment: I am native Arab, and though I read it couple of times, I could not really understand the meaning. I hope one might find the answer.

Comment: majja مج means "spit". I do not see any ambiguity in this hadith.

Answer (score 2):

> ...While I am in the world, I am the Light of the world." 6When He had said this, He spat on the ground, and made clay of the spittle, and applied the clay to his eyes, 7and said to him, "Go, wash in the pool of Siloam " (which is translated, Sent). So he went away and washed, and came back seeing... (John 9:6)

The above thing is talking about Prophet Jesus (pbuh) curing the blind (Refer Qur'an [3:49](http://quran.com/3/49)).

> Habib, either the son of Fudayk or Furayk's said that his father's eyes became
>   so white that he had no vision at all. The Messenger of Allah, praise and peace
>   be upon him, blew some of his saliva in to his eyes whereupon his vision was
>   immediately restored. He was even seen threading a needle at the age of
>   eighty!

Extracted from page 188, section Section 21 – The miraculous healing of the sick and the incurable, from the Book "PROPHET MUHAMMAD - [The Cure](https://madinasharif.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/ash-shifa-shareef-of-qadi-iyad-ibn-musa-al-yahsubi-radi-allahu-anhu.pdf) (Ash-Shifa)" by Judge Eyad. (I actually took it from "[Who had the most powerful spit: Jesus or Muhammad?"](http://dwindlinginunbelief.blogspot.de/2012/02/who-had-most-powerful-spit-jesus-or.html)). There are many other Hadith quoted in that section 21 of that book, **talking about the cure/relief by Prophet Muhammad's (pbuh) spit.** (Sorry I could not verify them from standard Hadith books).

As others have said and as it is widely believed,

- the spit of prophet (pbuh) was considered Barakah
- The water left over or the water falling from the wudu of Prophet (pbuh) was considered Barakah.
- The prophet (pbuh) touching a person after making some Du'a is considered Barakah.

etc.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't mean "ejected a mouthful of water" but rather "blow water"...
In Umdatul Qari (commentary on Bukhari) it's written:

> وَإِنَّمَا يدل على ممازحة الطِّفْل بِمَا قد يصعب عَلَيْهِ، لِأَن مج المَاء قد يصعب عَلَيْهِ، وَإِن كَانَ قد يستلذه.

It means that the prophet SAW was playing with he kids... The narrator (Ibn Shihaab) mentionned that for two main reasonز

> ومحمود نقل سنة مَقْصُودَة فِي كَون النَّبِي، عَلَيْهِ الصَّلَاة وَالسَّلَام، مج مجة فِي وَجهه لإفادته الْبركَة، بل فِي مُجَرّد رُؤْيَته إِيَّاه فَائِدَة شَرْعِيَّة يثبت بهَا كَونه صحابياً

- to prove that Mahmud bin Ar-Rabi was a sahabi
- for mentionning the barakah of this

Comment: Please add the English translation of the text in Arabic.